# If you can report risk ratio reliably, what are some reasons (if any) to report odds ratio instead?

Tags: self-study, odds-ratio, relative-risk

I know that in the case of case-control studies you should report odds ratio, because risk ratio cannot be calculated in this kind of study (I think this is what this question is about [When looking at the association between binary variables, when are odds ratios better than risk ratios and vice-versa?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94514/when-looking-at-the-association-between-binary-variables-when-are-odds-ratios-b)).

But if we have a study design allowing us to calculate risk ratio, are there some reasons to report odds ratio instead?

I find risk ratio much easier to interpret and communicate (and I guess it's the case for most people), but I was wondering if odds ratio could be superior in some other way I did not think of.

Thanks.

Comment: For your type of data do analyses to determine which of RR, OR is more constant over types of subjects, and use that.  You'll typically find that OR is more constant because it places no restrictions whereas for example a RR of 2 cannot apply to a base risk > 0.5.

Comment: Thanks @FrankHarrell. I don't have specific data for the moment that would make my question more specific, but the question has been on my mind a few times lately when reading introductory material on risk and odds. Your comment is useful and I'll consider it next time I have to make a choice.